# Add link to a specific report to sitemap in CRM 2011

Tags: report, dynamics-crm-2011, sitemap

I have a report called "Employee Resume" and I have received a request saying that it should be available in sitemap to make it more accessible. Is it possible to add a link to a specific report in sitemap in CRM 2011? I'm using SSIS for reporting.

Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See how to get the report URL:

> [MSDN - Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx#BKMK_OpenReportWithURL)

See how to add the report URL to your sitemap:

> [MSDN - Edit the site map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx#BKMK_EncodeAmpersandCharacter)

You can use your favorite sitemap editing tool, of course, instead of manually editing the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when I edit manually as u mentioned in MSDN - Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL, I get an error in Xml file saying helpId and id Entity is not defined. And I can't import the solution as well. It throws an error. When I click Technical details, it says "'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 184, position 172.". This is what I used for Url : <OrganizationUrl>/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Employee%20Resume.rdl&id=%7b8E6CB0B9-562A-E311-BB3A-00155D6DEE04%7d

Comment: I do not recommend manually editing the SiteMap due to a high possibility of errors, but to use a tool instead. See the SiteMap editor inside the XrmToolBox or the 'CRM Sitemap Editor' from Simpler Software for a more visual interface. Try building the URL with the provided in MSDN JavaScript function and then adding it to your SiteMap using one of the tools.